# Windows 10 is downloading

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

Windows 10 says it is upgrading on my laptop to Windows 10. What do I do next, I do not want it to download on my laptop. 
I haven't tried anything as I don't want to download on my computer.

Comment: "*Windows 10 says it is upgrading on my laptop to Windows 10*"? Do you mean your current version of Windows has indicated it is downloading Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

When windows 10 upgrades, the first phase is to download the upgrade. Once the download is completed, you still can cancel the upgrade. If you simply don't want to upgrade, this is the best option.

If you fear bandwidth problems, either restart your computer or find the process using task manager and end it.

Do note, if windows is actually upgrading your OS, make it finish upgrading. Once the upgrade is complete, go to start and search for `Reset pc` It should give you an option that says `Restore windows back to the previous version`. Its a waste of time but no data loss.

Keep in mind, that this is being given through Windows Update. Open Windows update, search for updates, when it says `Click here to upgrade to Windows 10` find the button saying `View all updates`. Usually the upgrade is listed as optional update, but it may be on the recommended updates. Right click the update and choose, hide update. This will stop it from updating through windows update. You can still upgrade through the GWX app in the taskbar, and you can restore hidden updates if you want to access it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If Windows 10 upgrade has started you can stop it going all the way by declining the End User Licence Agreement (EULA) which comes up about 70% through the upgrade process. Even if the upgrade completes you have 30 days to restore to previous Operating System via Settings/Recovery.